# "Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found. Try passing init = option to kernel" after installing Ubuntu with UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, uefi

I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS second system with windows 7, UEFI. Made a LiveUSB, downloaded, started the installation.

The installer showed four sections, one for efi already existed (windows loader seems named, 100 MB), the other three, ntfs. One of them I erased (of course, partition with windows I saved), and created two partitions - swap and `/`. The installation was successful, no errors. But after the reboot comes to grub, the choice of Windows 7 again returns to the grub, when choosing Ubuntu - gives black screen with error:

> [1.310472] Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found. Try passing init = option to kernel. See Linux Documentation / init.txt for guidance.

Besides, now will not ship LiveUSB.

Comment: Maybe this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Please fix the bootsector of your sda1 partition this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

This should fix your Windows error.

Comment: Thanks, yesterday I already fixed windows error with boot-repair

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8. It turned out that the problem was UNetbootin (the LiveUSB image), which I had created on Fedora. Once I created a LiveUSB from Windows using http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ and reinstalled Ubuntu, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the solution to this error turned out to be [disabling Secure Boot in the BIOS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx). Initially, I was not able to boot from my hard drive or from a Live DVD. However, I could boot from a live USB. Different distros behaved a little differently, but none would fully boot and no solutions others had posted worked for me. This was a Lenovo x201 laptop, after replacing Windows 7 with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows boot error sounds like you ran [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on the computer some time ago, then subsequently re-installed GRUB. Up to a couple of months ago, Boot Repair was aggressive in renaming Microsoft's boot loader (`bootmgfw.efi`) and replacing it with another copy of GRUB, which would create the problem you describe. If I'm right, re-running Boot Repair and using the Advanced option to restore backed-up files may fix that part of the problem. You'll need to boot from an emergency/live CD to do this, of course.

Your Linux problem is more obscure. It may indicate a problem in the initial RAM disk (initrd) or on your installed system. Either is a very strange error, since this is very basic stuff that should *not* be causing problems. A problem here is most likely a symptom of some other problem, like a disk that's full or otherwise failing. Perhaps more clues would be present in the Boot Repair logs; when you run that program, it spits back a URL with logs. Post that URL here for us to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer! Here are the logs from boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/6272359/

Comment: I can still add (may be it is important for finding solution), that before installing ubuntu, I used your program FixParts, because installer didn't see windows partitions.

Comment: After repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6272840/

Comment: LovinBuntu's suggestion for fixing your Windows partition (`/dev/sda1`) sounds promising to me. I'm still not sure exactly what's causing the Linux problem. Since you've just installed, the cowardly suggestion to re-install from scratch may be the easiest solution -- but do *not* install GRUB in `/dev/sda1`! GRUB needs to go in the MBR (`/dev/sda`), or occasionally in a Linux partition.

Comment: If I understand correctly from logs http://paste.ubuntu.com/6272840/, now I have two grubs, on /dev/sda1/ and /dev/sda/ ? That is, boot-repair installed grub on /dev/sda/ but didn't delete from /dev/sda1/ ? P.s. windows now ships normal

Answer (score 0):

...same case. I installed from USB stick and that was the reason: while writing the image with Universal-USB-Installer to the stick (from Win 7) my Virus scanner blocked writing of a file named 'autorun'. Adjusting Virus scanner to let 'autorun' pass and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and fixed it by replacing the battery on the motherboard. dell server poweredge 2850.